# which react native library should i use to access music files locally stored on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-sound

I want to access and run music files stored locally on android and ios devices.
I tried using react-native-fs but couldn't managed to access. So are there any other better libraries available to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.
I was finally able to access the music files / (or any files stored on an android device) in react native using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library.

I stumbled upon quite a few times using API constants provided such as *MainBundlePath*, *DocumentDirectoryPath*, *ExternalDirectoryPath* to name a few except trying *ExternalStorageDirectoryPath* which was really needed.

So below is the code (Provided by react-native-fs git repo):

```
RNFS.readDir(RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath)
.then((result) => {
console.log('GOT RESULT', result);
return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
})
.then((statResult) => {
if (statResult[0].isFile()) {
return RNFS.readFile(statResult[1], 'utf8');
}
return 'no file';
})
.then((contents) => {
console.log(contents);
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err.message, err.code);
});
```

Comment: It's got all files and log it in the result or ask the user to choose one of them like react-native-image-picker?